# Does a MySQL "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" replace the value even if the new value is the same?

Tags: mysql, database

For example:

```
INSERT INTO table (id,a) VALUES (1,2) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a=2
```

Will 'a' be updated with the value '2' even if the value is currently '2' in the database?

What happens really in this case?

Comment: I think it does not replace it - at least this is what happens with normal UPDATE queries.

Comment: What is your question again? Does it matter if 2 becomes 2 again?